# How do I profile a java server application using jprofiler9?

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

I have passed the "agentlib" flag. Do I also need to set trigger to get the snapshots? I actually wanted to profile the entire run (including heap/gc dumps, CPU profiling of methods etc) from start to stop of the application. Can someone let us know how we can do this for ENTIRE application run? The help is not very clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "offline profiling" in JProfiler and requires you to set up triggers.

You define a trigger for "JVM startup" where you start the recordings that you are interested in and a "JVM exit" trigger where you save a snapshot.

For more information, see

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/config/triggers.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help/info. Should I use the GUI (jprofiler GUI) still to set up these triggers OR is there a way to set these triggers/snapshots in some file, say config.xml file?

Comment: The reason I need this is because I am running this profiling session on a remote machine and working on a GUI remotely is painfully slow.

Comment: Further, I also wanted to know how I can create a new session without launching from GUI? When I clock on new session button, it asks if I want to launch from the GUI or attach to a running process. I do not want either. I just want to create a new session so that I can setup all my profiling info (CPU samples, GCs, triggers, snapshots) so that I can use this session ID in my java command line. Thanks for a way out for me :)

Comment: You create the session in the GUI and then you can export it to an xml file with Session->Export Session Settings. Use the integration wizard (Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration) to get the complete VM parameter for an offline profiling session that includes a reference to a config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another issue, which I raise as another question.